# adding items to dict of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Assume a dict whose keys is are hash values (or anything) and whose elements are lists of items that share that hash value.  One way to code it:

```
def add_item(dict_of_lists, item):
    key = item.get_key()
    if key in dict_of_lists:
        # at least one item already maps to this key
        dict_of_lists[key].append(item)
    else:
        # this is the first item to map to this key
        dict_of_lists[key] = [item]
```

Is there a more pythonic (or more elegant, or more efficient) way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would argue this is the most Pythonic way to do it. It's clean, elegant, and relatively efficient.

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` is the way to go IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using defaultdict, eg

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_of_lists = defaultdict(list)
dict_of_lists[key].append(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use `dict.setdefault`, which will only assign a value to a key if the key does not exist yet in the dictionary:

```
dict_of_lists.setdefault(key, []).append(item)
```

I find it quite legible, though if you're going for microoptimisations you might notice an empty list being created each time, whether needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a `defaultdict`:

```py
key = item.get_key()
list_with_default = dict_of_lists.get(key, [])
list_with_default.append(item)
dict_of_lists[key] = list_with_default
```